# Наложение ватермарка

Tags: php, watermark

Не могу наложить вотемарк, вроде всё верно. Думаю, что проблема в перезаписи изображения.

```
$image_path = "watermark.png";

$oldimage_name = "img.png";

function watermark_image($oldimage_name){
// получаем имя изображения, используемого в качестве водяного знака    
global $image_path;
$type = array_pop(explode(".",$oldimage_name));
list($owidth,$oheight) = getimagesize($oldimage_name);
if($type=='png') {
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($owidth, $oheight);
$img_src = imagecreatefrompng($oldimage_name);
imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $owidth, $oheight, $owidth, $oheight);
}
if($type=='gif') {
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($owidth, $oheight);
$img_src = imagecreatefromgif($oldimage_name);
imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $owidth, $oheight, $owidth, $oheight);}
if($type=='jpeg') {$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name);}
if($type=='jpg') {$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name);}
if($type=='PNG') {
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($owidth, $oheight);
$img_src = imagecreatefrompng($oldimage_name);
imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $owidth, $oheight, $owidth, $oheight);
}
if($type=='GIF') {
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($owidth, $oheight);
$img_src = imagecreatefromgif($oldimage_name);
imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $owidth, $oheight, $owidth, $oheight);}
if($type=='JPEG') {$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name);}
if($type=='JPG') {$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name);}
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($image_path);
list($w_width, $w_height) = getimagesize($image_path);
$pos_x = $owidth - $w_width-5;
$pos_y = $oheight - $w_height-5;
imagecopy($im, $watermark, $pos_x, $pos_y, 0, 0, $w_width, $w_height);
if($type=='png') {unlink($oldimage_name); imagepng($im, $oldimage_name, 9);}
if($type=='gif') {unlink($oldimage_name); imagegif($im, $oldimage_name, 100);}
if($type=='jpeg') {unlink($oldimage_name); imagejpeg($im, $oldimage_name, 100);}
if($type=='jpg') {unlink($oldimage_name); imagejpeg($im, $oldimage_name, 100);}
if($type=='PNG') {unlink($oldimage_name); imagepng($im, $oldimage_name, 9);}
if($type=='GIF') {unlink($oldimage_name); imagegif($im, $oldimage_name, 100);}
if($type=='JPEG') {unlink($oldimage_name); imagejpeg($im, $oldimage_name, 100);}
if($type=='JPG') {unlink($oldimage_name); imagejpeg($im, $oldimage_name, 100);}
imagedestroy($im);
return true;
}
```

Comment: 1. Отступы в коде ОЧЕНЬ помогают его читать.
2. Не могу наложить вотемарк, вроде всё верно. Думаю, что проблема в перезаписи изображения. - а что конкретно не получается то? Вываливаются ошибки? Картинка не создается?....

Comment: @Ale_x, изображение не создаётся

Comment: if($type=='png') {unlink($oldimage_name); imagepng($im, $oldimage_name, 9);}
if($type=='gif') {unlink($oldimage_name); imagegif($im, $oldimage_name, 100);}...

-_-

    switch (strtolower($type)) {
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'jpg':
            ...
    }

Comment: Понимаю, г-код, но это проблемы не решает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начинаем по частям:

1. Зачем 
     if($type=='png') и if($type=='PNG') и т.д.?
2. Определять тип изображение по его расширению полученного и имени - ну это совсем никуда. НА заборе тоже написано - а там дрова.

Код проверил токо что.
Водный знак в формате png.
Исх файл в формате gif.

Скрипт отработал

Answer (score 0):

Код ужасен, но он работает. 
Уважаемый, вы функцию-то вызвать не забыли?
Единственное изменение, которое мне пришлось сделать(кроме создания двух файлов - вотермарка и оригинала) - добавить в конце строчку

```
watermark_image($oldimage_name);
```

Однако, имейте в виду, что функция перезатирает файл, а не создает новый.

UPD: ну и проверьте владельца/права доступа к файлу.

Comment: Не забыл, тут только основная часть кода. В том то и дело, что он не хочет перезатирать картинку. Если изменить немного код и сохранять как новую картинку, то работает, а вот переписывать отказывается

Comment: ну и проверьте владельца/права доступа к файлу.// chmod и chown, если на линуксе

Comment: @knes из моего комментария вроде понятно, что права в норме

Comment: нет, не ясно. Сохранение новой картинки - это права на чтение на существующий файл и на работу с папкой.
А перезапись - это права на запись существующего файла.